# USB drives not recognized

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, usb, flash

On my school computer, I tried plugging in my flash drive, and I can hear the sound Win 7 makes when a USB is plugged in, but I can't see it in My Computer. Also, there are 2 other partitions of the HDD, which aren't visible on my computer. I checked in the BIOS, all USB ports are enabled. Also, the mouse and keyboard are wired USB.

How can I get it to recognize Flash Drives? Regedit and Gpedit is available.

Comment: Is the computer owned by the school? Is there a policy against using flash drives?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the administrator of the school's computer disabled accessing USB drives in Windows 7 for security reasons to prevent the introduction of malware to the school's computer via USB drives. For security reasons access to the two other partitions that aren't visible on that computer may have also been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer is probably added to a group policy which your system administrator has set up on the domain. You can use the USB only in power mode, like powering your mouse or keyboard, but you cannot use it for data transfer.

The only way you can have access to USB drives is to talk to the system administrator to remove your computer from that group policy.

The same thing with those 2 partitions. Only the system administrator or another domain or local admin can access them.